# Temporarily Scale Up Azure Web App RAM (e.g. App Service Plan) for Single Requests

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, autoscaling

We have an Azure web app used for internal reporting, and 99% of the time it can handle all the traffic / requests it needs to on the minimum pricing tier (3.5 GB RAM).

But there is one specific request to generate an Excel Report that temporarily requires ~8 GB of RAM to service (ClosedXML is a beast, and we've already minimized the peak RAM footprint in every way possible). Unfortunately, this requires not only the next pricing tier up (7GB) but the one after that, giving us 14 GB to play with.

This request only takes ~1 minute to service, so after trying everything else, I'm considering using Azure APIs to programmatically change the App Service Plan when the request comes in, wait the 10 seconds or so for it to kick in, then process the request, and scale back down afterwards.

Is this a sane approach, or is there some other feature I'm not aware of to temporarily perform a memory-hungry action? I considered an Azure function, but I've read those are limited to 1.5GB RAM... As far as I can tell, this work can't be subdivided up in any way without becoming an expert on manipulating the zipped-XML underlying Excel workbooks.

Comment: Why do it on azure at all? On prem hardware is still a thing.. Do it on a machine in an office somewhere; 8gb is pretty lowly for a desktop these days

Comment: sure you can scale it up, but you will have a downtime while it is vertical up or down scaling.

Comment: @CaiusJard Agreed wholeheartedly, but this is one of those situations where it's easier to use the wrong tool on hand for the job than to drive all the way to the hardware store to pick up the right one :)

Comment: Is it an option to have a big VM that sits round stopped/deallocated most the time but is started for running these reports, runs them, then shuts down again? I've done a similar thing in the past for media processing that wasn't time critical. I wonder if your occasional request that comes in can tolerate the wait time of launching/stopping the VM

Comment: @CaiusJard Most definitely another viable option. As you said, just maybe needs some finessing around putting off the response to avoid timeouts while waiting for the VM to start up. Perhaps make use of the 503 retry-after protocol.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds reasonable what you are trying to do, we are doing similar things where we scale thing up before running massive monthly imports, we scale both the front end functions and the back end CosmosDB and then scale back down again once the import is done so I don't think you will have any issues doing this.

On a side note there is no 1.5 GB limit on azure functions, it totally depends on the underlying hosting solution, you can host a function on a P3V3 App Service Plan or even bigger dedicated plans and benefit from the resources they provide but that is a different topic.

Answer (score 1):

No out of box from AppService (Plan). In similar situation, we started with an automation account but upgraded to LogicApps.

Using LogicApp as request broker, for specific kind of operation invoke `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/app-service-plans/update` to scaleup the AppService plan and after the successful completion scale down. Btw, hosting the LogicApp on the APIM as well before exposing the url!